# Does equality of the operator norm and the cb norm for every bimodule map over a C*-subalgebra imply that the subalgebra is matricially norming?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In this post, without further mention all C*-algebras are assumed to have an identity element and subalgebras inherit the identity.

**Question:** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a C*-subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}$.  Suppose that for every C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ containing $\mathcal{C}$ as a C*-subalgebra and every $\mathcal{C}$-bimodule map $\phi:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$, $\|\phi\|
= \|\phi\|_{cb}$.  Does it follow that $\mathcal{C}$ is matricially norming for $\mathcal{B}$?

**Definitions:**

- Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be C*-algebras and let $\phi:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ be a linear map.  Define, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\phi_n:M_n(\mathcal{A})\to M_n(\mathcal{B})$ by $\phi_n((a_{ij}))=(\phi(a_{ij}))$.  The *cb norm of $\phi$* is defined by $\|\phi\|_{cb}=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\|\phi_n\|$.  (The "cb" stands for completely bounded, and $\phi$ is called completely bounded when its cb norm is finite.)
- A C*-subalgebra $\mathcal{C}$ of a C*-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ is called *matricially norming* for $\mathcal{B}$ if for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and every $n$-by-$n$ matrix $(b_{ij})$ in the C*-algebra $M_n(\mathcal{B})$, $$\|(b_{ij})\|=\sup\left\{ \left\| \sum_{i,j=1}^n x_i b_{ij} y_j  \right\|: x_i,y_j\in\mathcal{C}, \left\| \sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^* \right\|\leq1, \left\| \sum_{j=1}^n y_j^* y_j \right\|\leq1\right\}.$$

**Remarks:**

- The matricially norming condition says that matrices over $\mathcal{B}$ are "normed" by contractive row and column matrices over $\mathcal{C}$. That is, for $B\in M_n(\mathcal{B})$, $\|B\|=\sup\|RBC\|$, where the sup is taken over all rows $R$ and columns $C$ of length $n$ of elements of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\|RR^*\|\leq1$ and $\|C^*C\|\leq1$.  (So that, for instance, it is readily seen that $\mathbb{C}$ is matricially norming for $\mathbb{C}$.)  Sometimes just "norming" is used instead of "matricially norming", but I am using the more descriptive term found in [Paulsen's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=VtSFHDABxMIC&lpg=PP1&client=firefox-a&pg=PA106#v=onepage&q=&f=false).
- The converse to the question holds.  That is, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a matricialy norming C*-subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}$, then for every C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ containing $\mathcal{C}$ as a C*-subalgebra and every $\mathcal{C}$-bimodule map $\phi:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$, $\|\phi\|
  = \|\phi\|_{cb}$.  This is what inspired the question, brought to me by a fellow graduate student after we had studied chapter 8 in Paulsen's book.
- The subalgebra of scalars is matricially norming for a commutative C*-algebra, so if there is a counterexample it is with a noncommutative $\mathcal{B}$.
- I believe that results in [this paper by Smith](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/reprint/s2-27/1/157) can be used to show that there is no counterexample when $\mathcal{C}=\mathbb{C}$.  It is shown there that if all bounded linear maps from all C*-algebras into $\mathcal{B}$ are completely bounded, then $\mathcal{B}$ must be isomorphic to a subalgebra of $M_n(C(X))$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and some compact Hausdorff space $X$.  But then if $\mathcal{B}$ is noncommutative, the transpose map should give an example of a map whose cb norm is bigger than its operator norm.
- For more on matricially norming C*-subalgebras, the [paper by Pop, Sinclair, and Smith](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6WJJ-45FCC3N-2B&_user=440026&_coverDate=08%252F01%252F2000&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1212354031&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000020939&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=440026&md5=7937279efde16ad4eccd2f43bdb09a6c) is a good place to start.

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken. I presume it is meant to point to the following paper: _Pop, Florin; Sinclair, Allan M.; Smith, Roger R._, [**Norming $C^*$-algebras by $C^*$-subalgebras**](https://doi.org/10.1006/jfan.2000.3601), J. Funct. Anal. 175, No. 1, 168-196 (2000). [Zbl 1003.46031](https://zbmath.org/1003.46031).

Answer (score 1):

Dear Jonas,
   My colleague Bill Johnson has drawn this to my attention.
   Your question has a positive answer after noting that a $C$-bimodule map lifts to a $C\otimes M_n$-bimodule map on $A\otimes M_n$ If $X$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over $A$ of norm 1 then for any row and column contractions $R$, $C$ over $C$ we have
$$\|\phi_n(X)\|=sup\{\|R\phi_n(X)C\|: \|R\|,\|C\|\leq 1\} =sup\{\|\phi(RXC)\|: \|R\|,\|C\|\leq 1\}
\leq \|\phi\|$$
showing that $\|\phi_n\|\leq \|\phi\|. Of course, the reverse inequality holds and we have proved that the norm and cb-norm coincide.
Best of luck with your studies,
Roger Smith

Sorry, I (mis)read your question rather quickly so the answer above is not an answer at all. Will think about it.